how do you call a method from a user control on button click from buttons outside a view
I have an application where the page has a bunch of views nested in a multiview control and each view has a tab container.  inside a specific view there is button that returns the user to the main view.  Inside the tabs there are user controls.
my question is how do i call a method inside one of the controls that is in a view with the button that returns the user to the main view?
<asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="MV" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="view"> 
  <asp:View runat="server" ID="view">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnReturn" CssClass="returnBtnLink" Text="Return To Locations" runat="server" OnClick="btnReturn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                <cc1:TabContainer ID="tcUser" CssClass="Tab" runat="server" Width="100%" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="true"  Style="width: 100vw; max-width: 58em; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; backface-visibility: hidden; background-color: transparent;">
                <cc1:TabPanel ID="tpUser" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="User Info" Width="150px" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <uc1:UserDetails runat="server" ID="ucUserDetails" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </cc1:TabPanel>

method i would like to call on btnReturn_Click that is in ucUserDetails:
 protected void setEditOff()
        {}

ii have also put it into a public so it can be seen if needed:
public void resetHistory()
        {
            setEditOff();

        }


In code behind on the main page, you can use this:
 this.ucUserDetails.resetHistory();

Of course the "this" is optional here.
So, it not 100% clear if you wanting to use general code in the main page, and want to call that code from the main page code behind.
Of course, there is also the reverse. You want to call some code in the main page code behind from the user control code behind. In this case, then I would add a event method to the user control, and thus just like say you drop in a button on a page, you have a "event" for that button, you can do the same for the user control (have a event for the user control that calls code on the main page).

not sure why that doesnt work.  i have this on the same page : public void fillList and that is accessible but the reset history is not .

If UC code works fine, then I don't see why exposing a public method to run the code would not work just the same. As I stated, it's not all that clear if you wanting to call code behind in the UC from the main page, or the reverse. However, if the UC code works fine as now, then adding a public method to expose that code and calling it should and would also work.  So, we are thus missing some details here that don't make sense. I mean it not at all clear how that UC now triggers or changes the view on the main page anyway. For that control to do so, it needs valid reference to main page.

im calling the uc code from the main page.  i can access another method from the UC on the main page that is also set as public void.  however the new public method is not found which is weird since it is directly after the other public method.

post more of the markup, and post the code being used then.

edit:   it was a visual studio error-- i closed all instances and reopened them and i was able to access the control.  Thank you for your help.
